# What are attacks against hash collision resistance property?

Tags: hash, attacks

From the definition, a collision would mean you would have to find any two arbitrary `x` and `y` such that `h(x) = h(y)` where `h` is some cryptographic hash function. This is different from a second pre-image which means you have to find some `y` such that given some specific `x`, `h(y) = h(x)` (where `x != y`). The key difference being that `x` is fixed upfront.

I can make many cases why weak second pre-image resistance can hurt you (e.g. replace a known-to-be-good hash of a message/file with a malicious message/file that has the same hash), but I can't immediately come up with an attack where a collision would help you much. What are some real-world or theoretical attack vectors where abusing a weak collision resistant hash could cause harm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hash collision in a signature is for example a problem in document signing if the attacker can provide both signed documents. Just imagine a case where somebody orders you to do some work and the conditions are inside a signed document. Once you are ready they present you with a different version of the document which contains a lower pay for you but which still matches the signature.